# Fragment setUserVisibleHint method is deprecated

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-lifecycle

I used this method to perform some task after the fragment was visible to the user.

Now, this method is deprecated and I am unable to find a proper alternative method which gives a similar callback.

As per the documentation they suggest to use `FragmentTransaction.setMaxLifecycle(Fragment, Lifecycle.State)` method but I am unable to find a similar callback and so my work is stuck here for a long time.

I have read from the [changelog](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment) for fragments :

> Max Lifecycle: You can now set a max Lifecycle state for a Fragment by
>   calling setMaxLifecycle() on a FragmentTransaction. This replaces the
>   now deprecated setUserVisibleHint(). FragmentPagerAdapter and
>   FragmentStatePagerAdapter have a new constructor that allows you to
>   switch to the new behavior.

If anyone could please suggest me a proper alternative.
Thanks in advance.